# javascript browser timeout second timer

Tags: javascript, timeout, alert

I am trying to set a session timeout with Javascript and looks like the alert is blocking the timer from starting. Here is my code:

```
var first_timer = 2 * 1000;
var second_timer = 8 * 1000;
var down = -1;

function initTimer() {
  down = setTimeout(processTimeout, first_timer)
}

function processTimeout() {
        down = setTimeout(logout, second_timer);
        alert ("Timeout of first timer, timerid:" + down );
}

function logout() {
  alert("You are logged out");
  window.location = "http://www.google.com"
}

function clearTimer() {
  if ( -1 != down )
    clearTimeout(down);
  alert("Restarting timer");
  initTimer();
}

initTimer();
```

When I run the above, I see the second timer only starts after the first alert is dismissed. How can I make sure the second timer starts immediately after first timeout even if the alert is not dismissed?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alert()` function blocks everything else until it is dismissed. You can use whats known as a modal dialog to create your own alert style message that does not block.

jQuery UI has [this feature.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am looking for a popup that emulates native mobile behavior while showing background content. I tried jquerymobile dialog but it seems to occupy the full screen.. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It most probably depends on the browser you are using. I'm not experiencing the issue you describe with latest Firefox.

But still, the second timer alert box won't be shown until the first one is closed.

This is because JavaScript interpreters are *not* multi-threaded. But JavaScript itself is heavily asynchronous, especially on long delay requests such as timers, AJAX and animations. This is what sometimes gives the feeling of multi-threading.

Indeed, in your code sample, the second timer started as expected. When I dismiss the first dialog box, let's say, 10 sec after it appears, the second one is immediately shown.
Nonetheless, and it may be your question, it will never be shown *before* you dismiss the first alert because alert is a synchronous call. So that the main event loop won't get the control back until dismissed.

A workaround for this situation is to use "HTML" dialog boxes as those provide by Jquery-UI for example.